# .htaccess RewriteRule Query String

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Firstly thanks for the support and sorry but I am new to RewriteRule.

I have the following url:

> https://www.example.com/jobs/?job_title=&specialisms=&location=&radius=200&cs_=&cs_=Find+Job

which I want to make into :

> https://www.example.com/(job_title)-jobs/in-(specialisms)/in-(location)

any help would be great.

Comment: I suggest you start with the documentation, where else? It is very well written and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: have the following easy test on search field but unable to get the internal rewrite working. 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1? [R=301,L]